# How to detect if tortoise models are in sync with the database schema

Tags: python, tortoise-orm

For a project I am using Tortoise as an ORM. And I would like to check if the schema of a given database is compatible with the models defined in Tortoise ORM.

Since Tortoise comes with a migration tool called aerich, I would have thought this would be as simple as running:

```
aerich migrate
```

and see if aerich would create a migration. However there seems to be a problem with this, see https://github.com/tortoise/aerich/issues/133 . Because when running `aerich migrate` after an `aerich upgrade`, then for some reason `aerich migrate` will always report `No changes detected`. This `No changes detected` even happens when there were changes to the models after the last migration was created, and hence the models are actually not in sync with the database. In particular there is no way to check if an `aerich upgrade` actually applied the wrong migrations, or an erroneous migration.

This later is of course a very bad situation to be in, so I was wondering if there is a way to detect that the database schema is in sync with tortoise models without using `aerich`.